# Why this layout constraint can't satisfy?

Tags: ios, autolayout, nslayoutconstraint

I have two UIView with fix size (30, 30), I want the views horizontal center in superview. here is the layout description.

```
H:[view1(30)]-20-[view2(30)]   
V:|-20-[view1(30)]   
V:|-20-[view2(30)]
```

and add a constraint at horizontal
     `view1.leftMargin = view2.rightMargin`

But these constraints not working as my expect.
the runtime warning say that unable to simultaneously not satisfy constraints. why?

I find a solution to center the views, which add two placeholder view in left side ,and right side, but I want to known why my first solution not working , how to known my constraints satisfy ? What did I miss?

Comment: vertical or horizontal or both ?

Comment: @Alok horizontal, sorry I modified the question.

Comment: k thanks for update, i have doubt on H:|[view1(30)]-20-[view2(30)]|. Please make it as H:[view1(30)]-20-[view2(30)] and remove view1.left = view2.right

Comment: Modified , my VFL not correct , please check, thanks,  I want  two views center in super view, I must set view1.left = view2.right

Comment: answer provided :)

Answer (score 0):

`view1.left=view2.right` and `[view1(30)]-20-[view2(30)]` is confict.
`[view1(30)]-20-[view2(30)]` means

```
view1.right+20=view2.left
view1.height=30,view2.height=30
```

so apple cannot make constrainsts.

Comment: thank you !, but I don't known why `view1.right+20=view2.left`  and `view1.left = view2.right` is conflict?

Comment: This obvious conflict. view1.left=view2.right  view1.right=view1.left+30 view2.left=view2.right-30.so you can know view1.left+30+20=view2.right+30. confict view1.left=view.right

Comment: Sorry, My last constraint is `view1.leftMargin = view2.rightMargin`, not  `view1.left = view2.right`, can you give the analysis for this situation ?

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to solve your problem and come to know that, with VFL, the only possible way for centering view in super view is through spacer views.

As you have defined your `view1` and `view2` also define two `spacer views`.

Then just paste this:

```
V:|-20-[view1(30)]
V:|-20-[view2(30)]
H:|[spacer1][view1(30)]-20-[view2(30)][spacer1(==spacer2)]|
```

And don't need `view1.left = view2.right`. Please remove it.

Output attached:
[image]

Comment: Thanks for your right solution, but I known that solution , I just want to know, why my  solution constraints conflict. why not satisfy. how to known  that?